# How to redirect error to route in Apache Camel

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-camel

My camel context sample.

```
<camel:camelContext>
    <camel:route id="r1">
      <camel:from="someEndpoint"/>
        ...
      <camel:to="to2"/>
    </camel:route>
    <camel:route id="r2">
      <camel:from="to2"/>
        ...
      <camel:to="to3"/>
    </camel:route>
    <camel:route id="r3">
      <camel:from="to3"/>
        ...
      <camel:to="to4"/>
    </camel:route>
    <camel:route id="r4">
      <camel:from="to4"/>
        ...
      <camel:to="exit"/>
    </camel:route>

    <camel:route id="errorProcessorRoute">
      <camel:from="???"/>
        ...Some action...
      <camel:to="exit"/>
    </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

I need if any error occure than procces route -> errorProcessorRoute.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch any error you could use the onException tag

```
<camel:camelContext>
   ....

   <camel:route id="errorProcessorRoute">
      <camel:from="direct:foo"/>
      ...Some action...
      <camel:to="exit"/>
   </camel:route>

   <onException>
      <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
      <to uri="direct:foo"/>
   </onException>

 </camel:camelContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<camel:errorHandler id="deadLetterErrorHandler" type="DeadLetterChannel" deadLetterUri="log:dead">
    <camel:redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="2" redeliveryDelay="1000" logHandled="true" asyncDelayedRedelivery="true"/>
</camel:errorHandler>
```

From [here](http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html).

Comment: You need to configure the errorHandlerRef on the <route> to tell the route that it should use that error handler

Comment: Could you show me some example? My idea was add global error handler and if error occure in any route deligate it to route (id="errorProcessorRoute") and do some steps (same for all errors) to sort up with it. Is it possible?

Comment: Use the errorHandlerRef attribute on <camelContext> to make it global for all routes, and then use the code above from the answer.